# Logging to network share not working via PS post reboot at startup

Tags: windows, powershell, logging

Getting ready to use a few scripts that I have had written for a while but was never able to solve one particular issue. Hoping to find a solution.

The project is to do a Win10 Build upgrade to around 900 machines in one weekend. Need to ensure they are back up in time and that the upgrade was successful.

Files are staged on a file share. Scripts are stored on the same share. A task is going to created with a bat file on each machine to go get the scripts and execute them.

In the scripts I have it set to record data and its progress to its own file on the network with the name of the file being *computer*.txt

**The Issue:**

After the upgrade finishes rebooting it will execute a task that is set to run 'AtStartup'. I have it reconnect to the network share immediately to start logging its status again. It will sometimes work perfectly fine and other times it will not. 50/50. The script works aside from this. Everything finishes fine.

**Why the logging?**

There are a lot of computers to watch all at one time with a limited number of people to watch over them and address issues. The logs will let me know where there might be a possible issue with how I have it logging. I would like to continue to get the data post reboots.

It doesn't appear to be a network issue because I have verified the machine is communicating.

Ive tried adding a sleep timer to give Windows 2 minutes to finish booting. That didn't help.

I am not sure where to look to find why it works only sometimes.

**Mapping of Network Share Path and setting file variable**

```
$Drive_Root_Path = "\\File Path\"
$Drive_Letter = "X"
Remove-PSDrive $Drive_Letter
$Drive = New-PSDrive -Name $Drive_Letter -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Drive_Root_Path

$Win10_Upgrade_Log_Folder = $Drive.Root + "Log Folder\"
$Log_File = $Win10_Upgrade_Log_Folder + $env:COMPUTERNAME + ".txt"
```

**Example how data is added to the file**

```
Add-Content -Path $Log_File -Value (Get-Date) -NoNewline
Add-Content -Path $Log_File -Value " Setting Executino Policy back to Restricted."
```

I know there are better solutions to upgrade Windows but with the options available to me, I had to come up with something. It works minus the part of logging after reboot.

Comment: This is probably due to the [Windows Fast Logon Optimization feature](https://support.microsoft.com/help/305293/description-of-the-windows-fast-logon-optimization-feature),basically the user is logged on using it's cached credentials prior the network and network shares are available. (Does it work when you redirect the log file to the local drive?)

Comment: It is at startup, not when a user logs in. There is no user logged in when it executes. Part of the script actually sets the autologon in registry back up. Reading/writing to local drive works fine. The autologon entries are stored locally in,a file from the first script because doing the upgrade erases them

Comment: Why map a network share for logging? Can't you simply use the UNC path to the share?

Comment: I believe what im building is a UNC path.

Comment: No, you are mapping a UNC path to a driveletter (X). That letter may already have been allocated by hardware or be a persistent mapping. The `New-PSDrive` will fail on those cases

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Theo to try using a UNC path instead of a mapped drive. I also advocate to try also using fully qualified domain names in the path. This makes your code even simpler:

```
$Win10_Upgrade_Log_Folder = "\\server.contoso.com\Log Folder\"
$Log_File = $Win10_Upgrade_Log_Folder + $env:COMPUTERNAME + ".txt"
```

And adding content is the same:

```
Add-Content -Path $Log_File -Value (Get-Date) -NoNewline
Add-Content -Path $Log_File -Value " Setting Executino Policy back to Restricted."
```

Comment: Setting up a few test machines now to see if it will work. the FQDN I already had specified though. Oddly enough I already had all the needed variables, I just needed to combine them differently. Not sure why I had chosen to use PSDrive in the first place. We shall see what happens.

Comment: I just finished the test on 3 machines upgrading at the same time. It worked all 3 times removing the `PSDrive cmdlets`. Still a small test case vs 900 but it is better than where I was at. If using `PSDrive cmdlets` at startup is the true issue, I would really like to understand why. At the same time I added complication using `PSDrive` that didn't need to be there.